# I'm trying to write this equation using latex, but I having some trouble

Tags: math-mode

[image: This is what I would like to tex.]

Note: The tex below is what I found on this site, but my project is "yelling"at me. Tell me that there is something wrong.

The important things being:

- `\underset` which takes two arguments, the first is put under the second.
- `\mathrm` to make `median` appear upright and differentiate it from a multiplication of 6 variables named m, e, d, i, a, and n.
- `\{` and `\}` need backslashes because `{` and `}` are part of the LaTeX base language.
- `\cup` which is a nicer symbol for a union.

> My code:

```
\documentclass[28pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=1.0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{chessfss} %chess figure for HW #2
\usepackage[english]{babel} %table for problem A.43
\usepackage{multirow} %table for problem A.43
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} color certain blocks in a table
%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}  just to show the margins
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{array}  %BETWEEN TWO 2-DIGIT NUMBERS

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}

\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{case}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}


\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}{C.35}
\textit{Use the formula $T(m,n)=\underset{row n of Pascal's triangle}{\mathrm{\left(1,n,\binom{n}{2},\dotsc,1 \right)}} \cdot \underset{m^{th} powers with alternating signs}{\mathrm{n^{m},-(n-1)^{m},(n-2)^{m}}}$ to calculate T$(10,3)$ and T$(10,4)$.}
\begin{flushleft}

\end{flushleft}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you showed the code you had used, and the error message you had, then someone would tell you how to fix it. Please edit the question to add the latex code that is producing errors.

Comment: You should format your code as code indenting it by 4 spaces or hitting thar button in editor which looks like `{}`. Also please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050). It should start at `\documentclass`, end at `\end{document}` and include only those packages and lines of code necessary to reproduce your results/issues.

Comment: You can't compile your whole line because you use `\dot` but should use `\cdot` there.

Comment: @Skillmon I changed the the \dot to \cdot and that worked. BUT now everything in the \underset{} is all smooshed together in one word and italicized.

Comment: That's because in `\underset` you're still in math mode. Enclose the text in `\text{}` (provided by `amsmath`) to get text formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I used stacks for the underset, and present the equation in display style.

```
\documentclass[28pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=1.0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{chessfss} %chess figure for HW #2
\usepackage[english]{babel} %table for problem A.43
\usepackage{multirow} %table for problem A.43
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} color certain blocks in a table
%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}  just to show the margins
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{array}  %BETWEEN TWO 2-DIGIT NUMBERS
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}

\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{case}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}


\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}{C.35}
\textit{Use the formula 
\[
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
T(m,n)=\stackunder[1.5\baselineskip]{\mathrm{\left(1,n,\binom{n}{2},\dotsc,1 \right)}}
{\stackunder{\textup{row $n$ of}}{\textup{ Pascal's triangle}}}
 \cdot \stackunder[1.5\baselineskip]{\left(\mathrm{n^{m},-(n-1)^{m},(n-2)^{m}},\dots\right)}
 {\stackunder{\textup{$m^{th}$ powers with}}{\textup{alternating signs}}}
\] 
to calculate T$(10,3)$ and T$(10,4)$.}
\begin{flushleft}

\end{flushleft}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]